# How to typedef in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have to use `this.state.<name>` multiple times, how should I replace it with a simple variable name? Like we use global variables in other languages such as C, C++.

Comment: Why would you want to replace it with a global variable. A lot of functionalities are tied to how state behaves

Comment: What's your purpose of using global variable?

Comment: I guess he wants a shorter alias. You can do that inside a single function by simply storing the `state` object in a local variable `render(){ const s = this.state; return <div>{s.value}</div>; }` but you can't use anything remotely global for this purpose. The whole functionality would fall apart.

Comment: how can I typedef "this.state.<name>"  with something ?

Comment: @Thomas yes, but there are a lot of functions in my code and even many items inside state for which i want shorter alias. So it is  not ideal to do it with "const" in all functions. so by the word "globally", i meant how to declare those shorter alias only once ?

Answer (score 1):

> @Thomas yes, but there are a lot of functions in my code and even many items inside state for which i want shorter alias. So it is not ideal to do it with "const" in all functions. so by the word "globally", i meant how to declare those shorter alias only once ?

you can't. Javascript simply doesn't provide that feature.

JavaScript as a Language doesn't have the compile-step where these aliases would be filled in with the real commands.

There are preprocessors, like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) for wich you could write a plugin.

There are task-runner like [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) for wich you could write a script to build that aliasing syntax (although it's most likely not valid JS)

You can check out [sweet.js](https://www.sweetjs.org/) maybe its functionalities already get you covered.

---

But maybe you'd consider learning JavaScript; realizing that JavaScript **is not** C and that you can't just transfer your coding style 1:1.

imo. the best Solution to get a bunch of shorter handles is [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). But this ain't aliases either; you need to understand what JS does here, and what the limits to this are.

Don't be too lazy to write a few more characters. Every modern JS IDE has an autocompletiton feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like this in render.

```
const { name } = this.state;

return(
   <div>{name}</div>
)
```

Now you can use it just with name as many times you want in render as well you can do in methods.

It is not like creating alias but we can optimize code.